# Managing grouped observable handling by type of group key in RxJava2

Tags: java, rx-java, observable, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am new to RxJava and am trying to use RxJava 2 to handle a stream of action events. I have two types in the stream (list) - "Immediate" which have to be executed in a blocking manner and "Deferred" which have to be executed non-blocking - both groups have to execute their set of actions in parallel. After reading about the options, I am thinking the groupBy operator is in play here but I am stuck on how to handle the subscription to the groups so the handling is appropriate. This is the code snippet I have come up with (obviously wrong) but I cannot think of the approach. I am looking for a suggestion on how to consume the two groups of observables correctly (so that immediate group executes in a blocking manner and the deferred group as non-blocking).  Thanks in advance.

```
    List<Map<String,String>> actionMaps = getActionMaps();

    if(actionMaps != null && !actionMaps.isEmpty()){
        actionMaps.removeIf(Objects::isNull);

        Observable.fromIterable(actionMaps)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())  
            .map(actionMap -> {
              String configForAction = jsonBasedConfigProvider.getValueForKey(Constants.CLASSIFIER_ACTIONS, getType() + "." + actionMap.get("name"));

              if(configForAction != null){
                  Utilities.convertJsonStringToMap(configForAction).forEach(actionMap::putIfAbsent);
              }

              return actionMap;
            })
            .groupBy(actionMap -> actionMap.get("executionType"))
            .subscribe(group -> {
                //Group all the immediates for special processing
                group
                .toList()
                .flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable)
                .takeWhile(actionMap -> "immediate".equals(actionMap.get("executionType")))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .blockingSubscribe(actionMap -> {
                    System.out.println("Key is: " + group.getKey() + ", thread is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ",item is:" + actionMap );
                    //ActionFactory.getAction(actionMap.get("name")).execute(actionMap);

                    //Any error handling required here?
                });

                //Group all the deferreds
                group
                .toList()
                .flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable)
                .takeWhile(actionMap -> "deferred".equals(actionMap.get("executionType")))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe(actionMap -> {
                    System.out.println("Key is: " + group.getKey() + ", thread is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ",item is:" + actionMap );
                    //ActionFactory.getAction(actionMap.get("name")).execute(actionMap);
                });

          });

    }
```

Comment: These types of questions are significantly easier to solve if you draw out your desired marble diagram.

Comment: Is it that immediate needs to be blocking, or rather that it needs to be completed entirely before any deferred items are handled?

Comment: Hello Jim - These actions are part of a web call. My intent is to make the web call wait only for the immediate actions to complete successfully and the deferred actions to be kicked off before the call returns.

Comment: Please add more information about blocking and non-blocking. If an immediate call comes it, it must be executed. While immediate call is executed another Immediate calle comes in. Should the second immediate call be queued until the first one finished? What if an immediate one is running and a deffered comes in? Should the deferred one execute on another thread? What if another deferred comes in while the first deferred ist executing? Please be more specific.